# How to include external header only librarys into gradle native builds with gradle's (5.3.1) new nativ eplugin?

Tags: c++, gradle, gradle-native

Evaluating gradle native i want to include a header only lib, {fmt}, to be used in a gradle native multiproject with the [new gradle native plugin](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-the-new-cpp-plugins).

I've tried including it via flatDir and maven repositories. The Documentation is only mentioning benary dependencies. But even then it seems that foreign code has to be extended with a build.gradle file. Below you see my last try

build.gradle at root

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'xcode'
    apply plugin: 'visual-studio'

    configurations {
        fmtLib
    }

    dependencies {
        fmtLib files(file("$rootDir/../fmt"))
    }
}
```

build.gradle at library which shall use {fmt}

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-library'
}

library {
    linkage = [Linkage.SHARED]

    targetMachines = [
        machines.windows.x86_64,
        machines.macOS.x86_64,
        machines.linux.x86_64
    ]

    baseName = "greeter"
}
```

greeter.cpp which shall use {fmt}

```
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY

#include <iostream>
#include "../public/greeter.hpp"
#include "include/fmt/format.h"

void Greeter::greet() {
    fmt::print("Hello, {}!", "world");
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << ", your name has " << getNameLength() << " chars." << std::endl;
}

int Greeter::getNameLength() {
    return name.length();
}
```

The example above leads to a compiling error which is clear because unresolvable dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the solution myself. Unfortunately gradle is not providing a better solution until 5.3.1 but a workaround can be done by

```
def fmtHeaders = file("$rootDir/../fmt/include")

components.main.binaries.whenElementFinalized { binary ->
    project.dependencies {
        if (binary.optimized) {
            add(binary.includePathConfiguration.name, files(fmtHeaders))
        } else {
            add(binary.includePathConfiguration.name, files(fmtHeaders))
        }
    }
}
```